# Search Engine query to URL

Tags: url, search-engine, dynamic-url

I'm wondering how to get my website to search for the keywords or query that is entered in to Google.

http://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs-in-Burnley

The is an example of a search term that I entered into Google and then once I clicked the link the website actually searched it.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: That may not be what happened, though - chances are that site had prepared a "jobs in burnley" page with the search term already filled in. Your search terms just happened to match exactly what they had already pre-filled.

Comment: and so do you believe that they could have prepared a site for all locations? There are 1000's

Comment: Totally. I've done this myself in the past, it's dead easy - take a database with place names; dynamically generate a page for each of them.

Comment: any idea how to accomplish this in wordpress?

Comment: Possibly - there may well be a plugin for it.  A cursory search turns up e.g. https://wordpress.org/plugins/landing-pages-leads-analytics-seo-content/

Comment: Thanks for your help :)